# How do I force .htaccess authorization to occur over ssl?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm trying to force a particular directory to require only allowed IPs and a valid username/password through basic authorization.  To ensure that the username/password are sent in encrypted form, I want the directory to also force SSL use.  Here is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
# Force HTTPS-Connection
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*)  https://www.mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

## password begin ##
AuthName     "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /var/www/admin/.htpasswd
AuthType     Basic
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 79.1.231.151 62.123.134.83
Satisfy All
```

Unfortunately, when I access that directory using http protocol, it is asking for the password before it redirects the page to the secure version.  This means the password is sent unencrypted.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting [SSLRequireSSL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequiressl) in your .htaccess file or the global Apache httpd configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrites and redirects are handled after autorisation. However: aliases in your httpd.conf are addressed first.

So what I did to get my http ://servername/webmail to https://webmail.servername was to put it in the httpd.conf like this:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
   Redirect permanent /webmail https://webmail.servername
</IfModule>
```

The basic autorisation can stay in your .htaccess and will be executed just once AFTER the redirect was executed...

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Apache config, add the authentication stanza to the `VirtualHost` that has SSL enabled.  Then the redirect will always happen first.

Also, using `mod_rewrite` to perform a simple redirect is a bit of overkill.  Use the [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive instead.  It's possible this may even fix your problem, as I believe `mod_rewrite` rules are some of the last directives to be processed, just before the file is actually grabbed from the filesystem.